# Number of homomorphisms from a group to $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Fix a group $\Gamma$ and a positive integer $n$. Let $c(q):=\lvert\Hom(\Gamma, \GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)\rvert$ denote the number of homomorphisms from $\Gamma$ to $\GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

Question A: is $c_n(q)$ a polynomial in $q$? I.e., does there exist a polynomial $P=P_\Gamma$ such that $c_n(q)=P(q)$ for all prime powers $q$?

This is known to be true if $\Gamma$ is finite or Fuchsian (which includes surface groups). For finite groups, see for instance the 2018 article ["Asymptotic bounds for the size of $\Hom(A, \GL_n(q))$" by Bate and Gullon](https://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/113941). For Fuchsian groups, this can be extracted from the discussions in the 2005 paper ["Fuchsian groups, finite simple groups and representation varieties" by Liebeck and Shalev](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00222-004-0390-3).

As the latter reference makes clear, (if $\Gamma$ is finitely generated), then this is about counting points on the representation variety $\Hom(\Gamma, \GL_n)$. Thus, it can be considered as a question in arithmetic geomety.

Added in response to comments: the question should be rephrased as:

Question B: is $c_n(q)$ "essentially" a polynomial in $q$?

Here by "essentially" we could mean a number of things, e.g., excluding some primes, or allowing quasi-polynomials, etc.

Even a broader question:

Question C: What do we know about $c_n(q)$ for groups $\Gamma$ beyond the ones mentioned?

Comment: This is not a polynomial when $\Gamma$ is a cyclic group of order $k$ and $n=1$; the formula is $\text{GCD}(k, q-1)$. Perhaps you want to ask for a quasi-polynomial? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-polynomial

Comment: It's strange. The Bate-Gullon article (linked in the question) claims that $c_n(q)$ (which they denote $X(n,q)$ is always a polynomial. But their reference for this is [this article](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82775425.pdf), specifically Proposition~4.1, and that article has the condition that (in OP's notation) $|\Gamma|$ is not a multiple of $p$, where $q = p^k$. The article also references [this article](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/~mwl/homjan02.pdf), which deals with that excluded case by giving polynomial *bounds* on $c_n(q)$, but doesn't claim that it's polynomial. (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) But then Bate-Gullon claims to prove things about the leading term of $c_n(q)$, which is not defined in the excluded case at all (such as observed by David E Speyer)! Either I am, or Bate-Gullon are, somewhat confused here; maybe I am misreading something.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda At the beginning of the "Preliminaries" section of Bate-Gullon, they say that their standing assumptions include that the order of the group is not divisible by the characteristic of the field.

Comment: Thanks all for pointing out my fallacy. I have put in an edit at the end of the question relaxing the requirements.

Comment: Names of @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda's [references](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417741/number-of-homomorphisms-from-a-group-to-mathrmgl-n-mathbbf-q#comment1072154_417741):  [Chigira, Takegahara, and Yoshida - On the Number of Homomorphisms from a Finite Group to a General Linear Group](https://doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1999.8398); [Liebeck and Shalev - The Number of Homomorphisms from a Finite Group to a General Linear Group](https://doi.org/10.1081/AGB-120027921).

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda I think Bate-Gullon also include in their assumptions "Suppose that $\mathbb F_q$ is a splitting field for $A$."